# Neo4j : Long delay and iteration dependance of a request with apoc.algo.cover

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

After having done :

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Frag(frag)
```

I applied the following request on neo4j from a jupyter notebook thanks to py2neo.

```
WITH [f1,f2,f3,...] as list1 
CALL apoc.algo.cover(list1) 
YIELD rel  
RETURN rel
```

The fi are the ID defined in my csv file, with "frag:ID" on the first line.

I tried different sizes of lists and I obtained the following result:
[my result with different sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgfDl.png)

I remark that the delay depend on the try of the same request. Is it normal ?

For my database of 45 GB, neo4j uses all my memory (no uncolored space memory with htop command). Do I have a problem of memory ? If I watch the activity of my CPUs, it seems that neo4j waits a lot (little activity) before that one of the CPU becomes full occupied.

Comment: I made an error on the picture. This one shows what happens sometimes on my computer. I make an answer to add my result.

Comment: Test  nodes  edges found"   First try  2nd try 3rd try 4th 5th
1 153     ?                          24s 0.79s   
6 153     6 287                  32s 0.9s 0.8s  
2 298   24 400                  45s 2,18s   
3 497   72 500                 1min17s 35s 6s  
7 591   94 576                 1min24s 12s 7s 8s 8s
8 749  152448                 1min49s 1min27s 13s 13s 13s
4 1079 329 016                 2min39s 2min14s 2min12  
5 2132 1 241 437         5min23s 6min14s

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ucl9lZFCZRCMxQCnQFE-iPionLroRgbI

Comment: I added my result on google drive.